# Can I add props to standard HTML tags using VueJS?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I know that I can create custom components using VueJS and add custom props to these components. Is it possible to add a custom prop to a regular HTML tag?

See this component with `button` and `color` props for instance:

```
<a button="round" color="red">A Red Round Button</a>
```

I would it to render as follows:

```
<a class="red round button">A Red Round Button</a>
```

Is it possible to do this with Vue? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I think a component is frankly easier, but you could write a couple directives.

```
Vue.directive("button",function(el, binding){
  el.classList.add("button", binding.value);
})

Vue.directive("color", function(el, binding){
  el.classList.add(binding.value)
})
```

Usage

```
<a v-button="'round'" v-color="'red'">Click me</a>
```

Here's the component version.

```
Vue.component("mybutton",{
  props:["button", "color"],
  template:`<a class="button" :class="[button, color]"><slot></slot></a>`
})
```

Usage

```
<mybutton button="round" color="red">Click me</mybutton>
```

Rendered

```
<a class="button round red">Click me</a>
```

[Example of both.](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/qmXaQd?editors=1010).

Comment: I love components, but sometimes I want to use standard html tags with custom props.  In other words, I don't want to use `<mybutton>`, but rather either the `<button>` tag, `<a>` tag or `<div>` tag each with a custom button prop.   Are Vue Directives the only (or best) way to achieve this?

Comment: @Moshe If you want your own custom attribute that translates into something else, like you're describing here, then the only way I know is directives. Maybe someone else will have a different idea.